# Transformar classe dentro de pacote

Tags: r, packages

Pessoal tenho uma matriz e quero transformá-la em outra classe específica de um pacote, `rgeos`, coloco o `@import` no pacote, dou `library` nele também, mas quando eu checo dá erro esse erro.

```
a = matrix(1, 2,2)
as(a, "gpc.poly")
Error in as(x, "gpc.poly"): no method or default for coercing "matrix" to "gpc.poly"
```

Como resolver?

P.S.: Já li o Hadley e o livro R packages, mas consegui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seguinte cabeçalho do roxygen2 importa corretamente o método que você precisa:

```
#' Hello
#' @export
#' @importFrom rgeos coerce
hello <- function() {
  a = matrix(1, 2,2)
  as(a, "gpc.poly")
}
```

Isso é um pouco estranho: para a função `as` funcionar corretamente ela 
precisa da função `coerce` do pacote `rgeos`. Lembre-se que o pacote precisa estar corretamente instalado.

O build do pacote retornou isso:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating test documentation
Loading test
Writing NAMESPACE
Documentation completed

==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source test

* installing to library ‘/home/dfalbel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
* installing *source* package ‘test’ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (test)
```

E a função funcionou corretamente:

```
Restarting R session...

> library(test)
> hello()
GPC Polygon
   Num. Contours:  1 
   Num. Vertices:  2 
   BBox (X):  1 --> 1 
   BBox (Y):  1 --> 1
```